# Parse and convert string to int rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

Hi I'm trying to parse an Xml file to add it to my database.

But one of the field is a string, i mean : "101m" and i wanna convert it to an int to have just 101.

Ty for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby, [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-to_i) is used to convert objects to integers. Here it is on the console:

```
>> "101m".to_i
=> 101

>> "101m23".to_i
=> 101
```

As you can see, `.to_i` starts from the left and gives up as soon as it finds something that can't be sensibly converted to an integer.